# Cloudera HBase ConnectTimeoutException

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, cloudera

I am trying to query HBase in a cloudera VM (5.5) But getting the following exception:

```
Error connecting HBase: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=quickstart.cloudera/192.168.1.117:60000]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(HConnectionManager.java:1592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(HConnectionManager.java:1618)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(HConnectionManager.java:1826)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.isMasterRunning(HConnectionManager.java:848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:2359)
```

Unable to figure out what could be the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: hi my answer was useful ? are you able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below methods.

**Method 1 :** 
Simple way to check is from browser

http://masterhost:60010.

**Method 2 :**

If you are querying from java program then general check before running any query could be calling the below methods from your client.

```
 public static void checkWhetherHbaseIsRunning() throws MasterNotRunningException, ZooKeeperConnectionException {
        // Create the required configuration.
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        // Check if Hbase is running
        try{
        HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Exception at " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

**Method 3 : from sand box** it will tell which port hbase master is running

```
ps -aef | grep hmaster
```

**Method 4 :** 
I think you can also check it from Cloudera manager since you are using CDH5.5

Answer (score 0):

You can run **netstat -ntpl | grep 60000** on machine 192.168.1.117 to confirm the port is linked to a process.

Run **ps -elf | grep **ProcessIDGotFromAbove** to check whether HBase master is running the process.

If HBase Master is running and port is also listening to 60000, then you can run the Linux command **lsof -i :60000 -r 2** then run the query. If the connection succeed to 60000, then in terminal, the connection status will be changed from Listening to Established.

Ensure you have disabled firewall & Master is running.